# Office incorrectly states "Programmatic Access To Visual Basic Project Is Not Trusted"

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I'm running a VSTO addin in Word 2013.  When I try to evaluate App.NormalTemplate.VBProject.Protection I get the proverbial "Programmatic Access To Visual Basic Project Is Not Trusted".  However, I had already enabled "Trust access to the VBA object model" and it's still not working.

Comment: Did you try to restart the host application right after changing the trust center settings?

Comment: I restarted several times. I've also checked to make sure that the setting has persisted and it did.

Comment: Try to do the steps described on the [VBA - How to programmatically enable access to the VBA object model using macros](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/02/29/vba-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros.aspx) page.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, that just modifies the registry by hand while Word is closed.  I did that as well, and still to no avail. :(